# How to write FireFox extension with Visual Studio using C# programming language?

Tags: c#, .net, javascript, firefox-addon

I was wondering if it's possible to write Firefox extension using .Net Framework?
Had anybody such experience in writing Firefox extensions using C# programming language?
Any good sites or guidelines would be very helpful.

[FFPlugin http://img81.imageshack.us/img81/3049/ffplugin.jpg](http://img81.imageshack.us/img81/3049/ffplugin.jpg)

Here is an example of what I need. Extension to enter phone number and to send SMS Message.
I draw it in Paint, so I'm sorry for having no artistic touch.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you're asking about writing an extension (and not a plugin), the best place to get started is [with the info at the Mozilla Dev Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extensions).

Konamiman is correct: extensions are mostly XUL (an XML grammar) and Javascript, packaged into a ZIP file with the extension `.xpi`. The various links from the page I linked should answer basic questions, like the one you posted above:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Building_an_Extension

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extension_Frequently_Asked_Questions

Answer (score 4):

Firefox extensions are written primarily in Javascript. See here: http://www.rietta.com/firefox/Tutorial/backend.html. So unless you can find a way to convert C# code/.NET Framework objects to Javascript, you are out of luck.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how you'd do for C#, but you can use XPCOM to call native code libraries: that's how the Glasser extension, for instance, is able to use the Windows-specific Aero effects.

IBM hosts a very good XPCOM tutorial at [DeveloperWorks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/co-xpcom.html).

Answer (score 3):

As has been observed by other respondents, Firefox extensions are primarily written in Javascript: but you're in luck, because [Script#](http://projects.nikhilk.net/ScriptSharp) is a free tool that enables developers to author C# source code and subsequently 'compile' it into Javascript.