# How should we build a Mozilla Firefox add-on with C# ?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to write FireFox extension with Visual Studio using C# programming language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680965/how-to-write-firefox-extension-with-visual-studio-using-c-programming-language)

How should we build an Add-On for Mozilla Firefox with C# ? 
Do you have some little code?
Thanks.

Comment: Except that the accepted answer isn't `c#` code.

Comment: The accepted answer isn't c# code, because as it states, you cannot use c# code to build Firefox extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Linky: [A thread already exists on this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680965/how-to-write-firefox-extension-with-visual-studio-using-c-programming-language)