# Is it possible to create a Firefox plugin that uses C# or C++ code? If so, how?

Tags: c#, c++, firefox, plugins

The idea is not to write the plugin itself using C# or C++ (although it would be nice if that were possible) but to have it access code written in C# or C++, preferably C#.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680965/how-to-write-firefox-extension-with-visual-studio-using-c-sharp-programming-lang - Yes you can

Comment: Possible duplicate ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680965/how-to-write-firefox-extension-with-visual-studio-using-c-sharp-programming-lang

Comment: you can visit mozilla developer website [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/reference), explain all languages for developp firefox module, pluggins...

Comment: Extensions in Firefox are not necessarily the same as plugins - the other question refers to extensions, which are typically javascript + xul, instead of plugins, which are typically native code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox plugins can be written using NPAPI, [which is a C API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Plugins), so work perfectly well from C++.  (This is probably the most common language used.)

Comment: Does the plugin developer have to compile a binary for every platform he wishes to target with the plugin?

Comment: @EricJ. Yes.  That's one huge advantage of extensions, which are typically XUL + Javascript - they're cross platform